# Partially rendering of 3D object

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

The problem at the moment is that my 3D object is only partially rendered. If i have a typical cylinder, where both ends are "filled", the ends render perfectly, while the cylinder itself is not. I have attache an example to illustrate.

This is how the code is built:

```
struct ObjMeshVertex{
    Vector3f pos;
    Vector2f texcoord;
    Vector3f normal;
};

struct ObjMeshFace{
    ObjMeshVertex vertices[3];
};

struct ObjMesh{
    std::vector<ObjMeshFace> faces;
};

ObjMesh myMesh;

for(size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i){
    ObjMeshFace face;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        face.vertices[j].pos        = positions[faces[i].pos_index[j] - 1];
        face.vertices[j].texcoord   = texcoords[faces[i].tex_index[j] - 1];
        face.vertices[j].normal     = normals[faces[i].nor_index[j] - 1];
    }
    myMesh.faces.push_back(face);
}
```

Setup:

```
    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_boxVAO);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_boxVAO);

    int sizeOfFaces = myMesh.faces.size() * sizeof(ObjMeshFace);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_boxBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _boxBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeOfFaces, &(myMesh.faces[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), (void*)offsetof(ObjMeshVertex, texcoord));        
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE ,sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), (void*)offsetof(ObjMeshVertex, normal));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Draw:

```
glBindVertexArrayOES(_boxVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, indicesize);
```

Where indicesize = myMesh.faces.size()

So my object looks like this:

[image]

The rendering ends up like this:

[image]

And im only rendering 1 object, not multiple, which seems a bit odd for this behaviour.

Spheres side-by-side:

[image]

Latest rendering:

[image]

Comment: It looks like a whole submesh is missing, which is probably either the fault of the importer/parser, or the obj exporter. Can you reproduce this with a simpler model (cube? sphere?). Maybe try verifying the model in an independent OBJ viewer (Assimp has a standalone one I believe).

Comment: I never had in success using Assimp, but i just tried to render af sphere which failed. Although if i init my indices and vertices manually from a printout in my parser it renders fine. I suspect there might be something wrong with the faces part of my code which i cant really manage to figure out. Image is attached.

Comment: Are you sure the obj writer is not emitting quads? Faces with more than 3 vertices are allowed per the obj specification. You'll need to triangulate them.

Comment: Also re: Assimp, you don't actually have to use or compile their code, but I believe there is a standalone executable OBJ viewer they provide that you can just download and click on to view an OBJ. Should give you an idea if the mesh itself is valid.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to triangulate. That fixed alot on the sphere. Except a small hole on the top and half of it missing. I will take a look at their parser.

Comment: @Tim, is there a chance to find an example on how i can use the 3rd. party library on its own? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, indicesize);
>
> Where indicesize = myMesh.faces.size()

And that's the problem. The last argument to `glDrawArrays` is not the number of primitives to draw (triangles in your case), but the number of array elements (vertices) and thus should be `3 * myMesh.faces.size()`. So at the moment you're only drawing about a third of all your triangles.

Comment: I need to update my code. I have changed it to         `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 7055);` 7055 is the same as the amount of faces. And as i can smell in the baker right now, it should be 7055*3. Damn.

Comment: @JavaCake If you have 7055 faces, then it should be `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 21165)`. That's the whole point of my answer.

Comment: Very nice spotted. You made my day! If you come to Denmark, feel free to visit me for a beer or ten :-)

Answer (score 2):

usually there could be multiple explanation to this problem.

1. The OBJ loader is broken or do not consider all the different OBJ features and therefore you drop a bounce of vertices/faces in the load
2. The OBJ file is not triangulated though, in this case, you don't usually loose entire pieces of a "structure" but you just notice malformed faces.
3. You have a culling problem and therefore, some of the faces are drawn by your calls but not written on screen by the face culling algorithm of Opengl. To troubleshoot this problem, try to disable the Face Culling in OpenGL using the glDisable statement. it is very easy to test. In case it is the issue, pay attention to not keep disabled the culling in your production version of the SW since face culling saves your life in terms of performances.

I hope this helps

Comment: I have attached whats being rendered so far. I have made sure that my object is triangulated. I have checked out the faces and compared to the vertices and normals, which seems to look alright. `Point 3` looks interesting, but when do i have to disable this?

Comment: As an addition i am trying to load my object in one array `posX,posY,posZ,normX,normY,normZ` instead of the primary method i was using.

Comment: As you can see on the rendering the flat surfaces are rendering quite fine. The top is rendered and the "front".